# If I train a skill I already have via a feat, do I get to retrain that skill?

Tags: feats, skills, star-wars-saga-edition, retraining

If a character trained in Perception in *Star Wars Saga Edition* later buys *Force Perception* (Train Perception, and roll UtF for it instead), can the character retrain the skill training lost?

The interactive Excel character sheet I'm using lets me do so, but I'm not sure if that's in the rules or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Force Perception** (Saga Book page 101) You can make a Use the Force check instead of a Perception check to avoid surprise, notice enemies, sense deception, or sense influence (see the perception skill, page 70)

However perception (page 70) Allows you to do all those but also Eavesdrop, Hear distant noises and definately not listed under those of **Force Perception** "Search"

This strictly reads to me that these ranks would not be available to repurchase, instead the force has given the character the supernatural (superforceal?) ability and senses in the areas specified, the character remains a regular bumbling doofus if they have a perception of 1 and loose their keys; certainly as a GM I would run it this way, yes, Jedi gain amazing powers, but they are focused and selective, and certainly not enough to replace such an all-encompassing skill as perception (to me) not that Force Perception isn't pretty damn good anyway!